# Where to learn Athabascan grammar?

Tags: grammar

I want to try and understand Athabascan grammar, but I don't know very much about it, and, because of this I also don't know what kind of Athabasca language I want to learn. I have looked on Wikipedia and I have found it fairly helpful, but where/how might I get a fairly complete understanding of the languages?

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion 1 is to pick one language as your "wedge" into Athabaskan, either Navaho (very many resources) or Slave (one very good one). Alternatively, for snippets across Athabaskan, you could try Fernald & Platero 2000 *The Athabaskan languages*.